# How to simplify repeating variables in where clause for multiple columns SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, substring

I know there has to be a better way to evaluate a set of repeating variables against multiple columns. I've been searching for a while and still don't have a great solution. Is there a better way to do this?

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE 
  (SUBSTRING(COLUMN1,1,3) IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4'...REPEATS to 30)  
OR SUBSTRING(COLUMN2,1,3) IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4'...REPEATS to 30)  
OR SUBSTRING(COLUMN3,1,3) IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4'...REPEATS to 30)  
OR SUBSTRING(COLUMN4,1,3) IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4'...REPEATS to 30)  
OR SUBSTRING(COLUMN5,1,3) IN ('val1','val2','val3','val4'...REPEATS to 30))   
...REPEATS 5 MORE TIMES
```

Comment: Are you just looking to do it in a query, or are you looking for design advice? Max's answer is fine if you're only looking for a query solution, but if you can make other changes, there are more possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One good way to get reasonable performance from this type of query is to insert the `'val1', 'val2', ...` values into a temporary table, then join against that temporary table.

We start with some sample data:

```
USE tempdb;
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Items') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Items;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Items
(
    ItemID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
        CONSTRAINT PK_Items
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , col1 varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , col2 varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , col3 varchar(30) NOT NULL
    , col4 varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY];

INSERT INTO dbo.Items (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
VALUES ('value0', 'value02', 'value03', 'value04')
    , ('value11', 'value21', 'value31', 'value41')
    , ('value5', 'value6', 'value7', 'value8');
```

To find desired rows, we insert the search terms into a temporary table, then join against it:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#SearchItems') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #SearchItems;
CREATE TABLE #SearchItems
(
    val varchar(30) NOT NULL
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
);

INSERT INTO #SearchItems (val)
VALUES ('value2%')
    , ('value03%')
    , ('cow%');

SELECT i.*
FROM dbo.Items i
    INNER JOIN #SearchItems si 
        ON (i.col1 LIKE si.val)
            OR (i.col2 LIKE si.val)
            OR (i.col3 LIKE si.val)
            OR (i.col4 LIKE si.val);
```

The output from the query above:

```
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| ItemID |  col1   |  col2   |  col3   |  col4   |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|      1 | value0  | value02 | value03 | value04 |
|      2 | value11 | value21 | value31 | value41 |
+--------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: I thought about that as well. If I don't know the literal value of the variable would this still work? I am using substring to pull back anything after 'val' when really what I need to pull back is val%. Not sure if this is making a whole lot of sense; the values would look more like this 'car%','bar%','sar%','mar%'.

Comment: I use a `LIKE` comparison in my join; however you could use a substring there instead.  It won't perform quite as well, but I still think putting the search terms into a temp table, then joining to it is more efficient.

Comment: Wrote that before the rest of the answer. Thanks a lot, this should help! I'll finish becoming a member so I can give you a vote :)

Answer (score 2):

A construct using the [Table Value Constructor (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) will save you some typing.

```
select T.*
from dbo.T
where exists (
             select *
             from (values(T.COLUMN1),
                         (T.COLUMN2),
                         (T.COLUMN3),
                         (T.COLUMN4),
                         (T.COLUMN5)) as C(Val)
             where substring(C.Val, 1, 3) in ('va1','va2','va3','va4')
             );
```